# How to have the ECL stub schema created in schema publication, and stub components in another?

Tags: ecl

My ECL provider is working, meaning I can view/browse external images through the provider icon in the Tridion GUI.

Now I want to start linking to the ECL items from my components MM-link fields. But I have an issue with this.
We have all our schemas defined in a Schema Master publication. But I have my ECL StubFolder setup to point to a child publication below Schema Master, lets say Master Content, because I want any stub components (= content) to be created in there. So the stub ECL schema is then created in that Master Content publication, and unavailable in my Schema Master publication to use in my MM-link fields???

The only way I see around this is either localise my schema(s) in Master Content and add the ECL stub schema as allowed schema in my MM-fields. Or define my StubFolder to be located in the Schema Master publication, but in that case contents will be created in there?

How to solve this in a nice way?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to add the stub folder at the level you need the schema.

In the ECL design we do not consider the stub components to be "content". They are simply placeholders. If you want to add metadata in a lower publication, then you can indeed localize at that level and set the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that :

- External Content Library multimedia type is added as "Allowed media types" on the Stub schema, NOT on your Visual MM-schema.
- On your Visual MM-schema : adding the Stub schema as allowed schema on the MM link field should be enough.

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. In the mean time I got it working, however I think the location of the StubFolder is an issue. I updated my question above to indicate my problem with this.